# Long webpage being cut off

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am building a music player website, and one of the pages has a place to view your playlist. In testing it, I found that on my playlist with 143 songs(a long page), the page cuts off some of them. I am using a table with each row representing one song, but the page cuts off about 6 rows before the end, even cutting off partway through one row. The entire page on a computer is abour 11000px long.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWg0Z.png)

I have tried margin and padding-bottom on the table, a container div around the table, parent elements up the page and even the entire body. I have tried modifying the height of the table, its parent div and the page between the amount of pixels the table should need, 100%, and auto. The height changing had little effect, and no container or table height properties are fixed, they all use %. The margin and padding actually cut off about 10 more rows of songs when I tried it. I've also give elements the overflow property already. Auto seems to work the best, which is what it's on right now, but i've experimented with scroll and it didn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: A table on its own should not get cut off.  Is there more context you can give about the rest of the page? It sounds like a container size.  Try removing the height and just letting it be auto - usually adding heights leads to problems.  Also, I would say that it is semantically better to use a list than a table - you can use flex or grid to layout each individual item, depending on need.

Comment: Just, really, show your code. Not a wall of code, just the part that's not working and its containers.

Comment: <div class="playlist_viewer">
            (other content)
            <div class="container">
                <table class="playlist_songs">
                    (tr and tds generated by js in here)
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Tom, thanks so much. I was testing a bunch of the things you suggested and something worked, it is now fixed